# How to stop yarn-workspace from complains unmet peer dependency?

Tags: npm, yarn-workspaces

When specify vue as peerDependencies in my component workspaces, all module complains `unmet peer dependency`(no local projects use these component). When check with `yarn why components`, it says something like:

```
=> Found "components@1.3.1"
info Has been hoisted to "components"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "workspace-aggregator-3f018756-4197-4f75-abdb-939cd7a64a8e" depends on it
   - Specified in "dependencies"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#components"
Done in 1.50s.
```

How stop these warning?